# "The decision of the Competent Authority of the Board shall be final and binding on the candidate." what is the meaning of binding here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"The decision of the Competent Authority of the Board shall be final and **binding on the candidate**."

Can anyone make me understand what is the meaning of the statement especially the bold part?

I am really having a hard time to understand this.

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries [**binding**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/binding) (of an agreement or promise) *- involving an obligation that cannot be broken.*

Comment: Also, when used after the noun, the adjective *binding* needs to be followed by the preposition *on* if it introduces those who are subject to the obligation (or, in this case, to the decision).

Answer (score 1):

***Binding*** is an adjective and means **OBLIGATORY** here.

According to Merriam-Webster's:

***binding***

adjective

: imposing an obligation

'***Binding on***...' is typical for legal texts.

Here's an example from Reverso.context.net:

Its decisions cannot be appealed and are *binding on* all other courts.

Answer (score 0):

> "The decision of the Competent Authority of the Board shall be final
>       and **binding** on the candidate."

**binding**  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/binding)

> not to be avoided or broken:

Thus the candidate must take action, not to delay or avoid its terms and cannot break the terms of the contract.

From Old English, late 14c., "serving to bind," past-participle adjective from bind (v.). Meaning "**having power to bind**" is from 1610s.